How to transform a univariate polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ into a multivariate Boolean polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2^n$
# sage
F=GF(2^8,'a') 
R=PolynomialRing(F,"x,y") 
R.inject_variables() 
f=x*y-1

How can we transform $f$ into multivariable Boolean polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2^8$, which includes variables $x_0,…,x_7$ and $y_0,…,y_7$
(16 variables in total), and has an algebraic degree of $2$?

Note that this derivation is tied to the polynomial basis selected for $GF(256)$ (which is tied to a pseudo-Conway polynomial IIRC)
Here's some sagemath
GF2 = GF(2)
MVPR2 = PolynomialRing(GF(2),8,var_array=['x','y'])
F = GF(2^8,'a')
F.inject_variables() 
xx = sum([a^i*MVPR2.gens()[2*i] for i in range(8)])
yy = sum([a^i*MVPR2.gens()[2*i+1] for i in range(8)])
xx*yy-1

